# Dax 30 Portfolio optimisation

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization, tracking-error

Let's say I have a return forecast for each stock in the DAX index. I also have a covariance matrix for these 30 stocks.

I want to solve for the 30 weights  by maximising the forecast portfolio return, subject to tracking error constraints for each sector being less than 1%.

Is this a convex problem? Could  there exist multiple local minima?

Comment: Please don’t remove useful content.

Comment: Indeed as someone states below if the variance covariance matrix is positive semi-definite you should get a global maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The problem being convex depends on the structure of the quadratic constraints in this case, particularly if the quadratic part is positive semi-definite. So you need to write out the constraints in matrix form and do the algebra to check.